# Assign array elements among 3 variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var Set = ("BENELUX,Luxembourg,PP3a,Western_Europe,France,PP6a").split(',');
```

Working sequentially, I'd like to take 3 elements at a time and assign each to a variable.  The result I'd like is:

```
var Aggreg = ["BENELUX", "Western Europe"]
var Country = ["Luxembourg", "France"] 
var Product = ["PP3a", "PP6a"]
```

The order of elements in 'Set' will always be sequential and will always be a multiple of 3.  I'm sure there's a clever, efficient way to do this.  Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want the variables to contain a string or an array?

Comment: I need them to be arrays

Comment: The expected result is more than three elements at a time

Comment: And do you want a single string in the arrays, like `["BENELUX, Western Europe"]`, or do you want each element as it's own string, like `["BENELUX", "Western Europe"]`?

Comment: @Silverburch Check to see if my answer gives the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to get each part into an array inside a single object, and then use a destructuring assignment to assign individual variables, like so:

```js
var Set = ("BENELUX,Luxembourg,PP3a,Western_Europe,France,PP6a").split(',');

var {Aggreg, Country, Product} = Set.reduce(function (result, curr, index) {
  if (index % 3 === 0) {
    result.Aggreg.push(curr);
  }
  else if (index % 3 === 1) {
    result.Country.push(curr);
  }
  else {
    result.Product.push(curr);
  }
  return result;
}, {Aggreg: [], Country: [], Product: []})

console.log(Aggreg);
console.log(Country);
console.log(Product);
```

Comment: A bit too complicated IMO

Comment: @soywod It does the exact same thing yours does, just with 1 iteration of the array, rather than 3. Reduce is a pretty common looping structure in JavaScript - not sure what is complicated here

Comment: Why the downvote? (Not my answer, but this answer is correct...)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either.  The single iteration of the array is exactly what I need given that 'Set' could potentially be big.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Silverburch You're welcome. If you found this answer helpful, be sure to upvote and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructuring assignment, increment variables to reflect indexes

```js
var set = "BENELUX,Luxembourg,PP3a,Western_Europe,France,PP6a".split(",");

var n = 0, m = 3;

var fn = (arr, a = 0, b = 3) => [arr[a], arr[b]];

var [Aggreg, Country, Product] = [
  fn(set),
  fn(set, ++n, ++m),
  fn(set, ++n, ++m)
];

console.log(Aggreg, Country, Product);
```

alternatively

```js
var set = "BENELUX,Luxembourg,PP3a,Western_Europe,France,PP6a".split(",");

var fn = function* (arr) {
  var n = 0, m = 3;
  while (m < arr.length) {
    yield [arr[n], arr[m]];
    n += 1; m += 1;
  }
};

var [Aggreg, Country, Product] = fn(set);

console.log(Aggreg, Country, Product);
```

Comment: re check the desired output. Aggreg should be every 3n, Country every 3n+1 and Product every 3n+2

Comment: "Set will always be a multiple of 3" implies to me that it can have `3n` number of elements, this solution only handles 6 elements

Comment: @mhodges Not following what you mean?

Comment: This doesn't handle more than 6 elements in `Set`

Comment: @mhodges How so?

Answer (score 1):

Just filter your array using the modulo (if you are sure about your data - in this case, be sure to get a multiple of 3 array size) :

```js
const data = "BENELUX,Luxembourg,PP3a,Western_Europe,France,PP6a".split(",")

function extract(data, shift) {
  return data.filter((value, index) => (index % 3) === shift)
}

const Aggreg = extract(data, 0)
const Country = extract(data, 1)
const Product = extract(data, 2)

console.log(Aggreg, Country, Product)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could make use of a simple `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
var Set = "BENELUX,Luxembourg,PP3a,Western_Europe,France,PP6a".split(',');

var Aggreg = [],
    Country = [],
    Product = [];


Set.forEach(function(item, index) { //For each item in the array
  switch (index % 3) {              //Get remainder of index/3
    case 0:
      Aggreg.push(item);            //If 0, Aggreg
      break;
    case 1:
      Country.push(item);           //If 1, Country
      break;
    case 2:
      Product.push(item);           //If 2, Product
  }
})

console.log(Aggreg, Country, Product);
```

Comment: A downvote on a correct answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Not a huge fan of impure functions, but I will upvote for a correct answer and to offset the random downvote. lol

Comment: @mhodges Appreciated! I do somewhat regret littering the scope but oh well, I guess it's got readability going for it :P